# Mi base de datos no se conecta al PHP

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

Este es mi codigo php con la conexión y todo, pero al insertar los datos en el html, no se reflejan en la base de datos.

```
`<?php  
    $servidor="localhost";
    $usuario="root";
    $clave="";
    $baseDeDatos="respuesta";
    $enlace = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $baseDeDatos);
    if (!$enlace){
        echo "Error en la conexión con el servidor";
    }
?>
```

Comment: @BetaM realmente en producción no convendría mostrar mensajes de error internos  del SGBD, es información que le encanta a los hacker. Es mejor un mensaje personalizado, como de hecho ocurre en el código de OP. Dicho eso, la pregunta en sí no es clara: 1. Habla de inserción, pero no muestra ningún código de inserción; 2. No dice qué ocurre, si muestra el mensaje de `Error en la conexión...` u otro mensaje. Patricia, pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta aclarando esos dos puntos.

Answer (score 0):

Esto debería servirte:

```
$db = "respuesta";
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pw = "";

$conexion = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw);

if($conexion->connect_errno) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conexion->connect_error);
   exit();
} else {
   $database = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno ese código está correcto no hay errores. Verifica la conexión de la base de datos colocando un else:

```
`<?php  
$servidor="localhost";
$usuario="root";
$clave="";
$baseDeDatos="respuesta";
$enlace = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $baseDeDatos);
if (!$enlace){
    echo "Error en la conexión con el servidor";
}else{echo "Conectado";}
```

?>

Si no hay errores debería aparecer en tu pantalla conectado. Ahora bien tu hablas de Inserción de datos deberías entonces tener una consulta o query sql para insertar los datos y en este codigo no lo estas mostrando. Algo así:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable ( nombre,apellido,cosa) WHERE id =? ";
    mysqli_query($enlace,$sql);
```

Comment: Cuando hagas sugerencias del tipo **algo así** no puedes ser ligero. Normalmente los campos **id** asocian idea de unicidad. Si el id existe la cláusula de inserción en situaciones normales va a fallar. Además del defecto del uso de marcador posicional que te señala @BetaM que se usa con sentencias preparadas. Te recomiendo leer [answer]. **Gracias por tu interés en colaborar**.